# Canvas - How to draw a growing trail

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs

I want to draw a growing trail behind an moving object. I know this look quite easy :) But there are some constraints :

- the trail must have some homogeneous transparency
- and i can not use caching methods because of performance issues

I have tested 2 ways :

One with lineTo() and incrementing stroke width, but the alpha transparency is not homogenic...

https://jsfiddle.net/zOgs/9ntajsa1/

One with lineTo() and circles to fill the blank, transparency is OK but there is a strange behavior when drawing from left to right, negative space appears...

https://jsfiddle.net/zOgs/psa3x9y2/

I also try to use compositeOperation with something like this, but it's messing with my background...

```
trail.alpha = 0.5;
trail.compositeOperation = 'xor';
for(var i=nb; i>=0; i--) {
    trail.graphics.drawCircle(points[i].x,points[i].y,size/2).closePath();  
}
```

I can't find a valid solution to this problem and i am beginning to despair :(

Comment: Your first example seems to work well. Do you want to have the shape that is drawn on the screen without the uneven coloring of the shape?

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a better way to do this, but here is an easy way: Use an off-screen canvas to draw the trails, then display that canvas as a bitmap child of the main stage.

Here is a fiddle based on your first one:
https://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/9ntajsa1/1/

```
// Canvas to draw to:
var offCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var offStage = new createjs.Stage(offCanvas);

// Add the offStage to the main stage.
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(offCanvas);
stage.addChild(bmp);
bmp.alpha = 0.1;

// Still get events from main stage  
stage.addEventListener('stagemousemove',onMouseMove);
```

Comment: Nice! If the individual circles of the path don't need to be individually managed and if the questioner's design permits, they might draw the set of semi-transparent circles directly to a native in-memory-only canvas. I'm thinking performance considerations with this idea.

Comment: @Lanny Thanks ! Good idea. I tested it successfully, it's great, but there is still performance issues since two or more objects are moving simultaneously... even with programmaticaly canvas created and not appending it to the DOM, as markE pointed out :)

Comment: This approach is effectively identical to using cache(), but introduces a little bit more overhead in managing two stages. Using cache shouldn't introduce much of a performance hit, especially if you can have all of your instances sharing a cache. Here's an updated version of Lanny's example showing this approach: https://jsfiddle.net/9ntajsa1/3/